# Mysql join query works in Mysql Workbench, but hangs at PyDev

Tags: python, mysql, pydev, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have been trying to run this query in PyDev environment for a while, but it just hangs there.

The tables involved are large (tweets around 700,000 and user about 400,000). I have all the indexes sorted out. I tried to run the query at Workbench and it works perfectly within seconds, but just hangs while executed in Eclipse...

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id, user, hashtags FROM users JOIN tweets ON users.user_id = tweets.user")
```

It seems that I don't understand the buffering associated with executing at Workbench vs any other environment...!

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: What part hangs? You might check the DB logs and see if you can see the query execute. Also, are you listifying the results? Or are you pulling them one at a time in a while loop?